# TypeError when saving tif with rasterio using "rasterio.open"

Tags: python, rasterio, numpy, save

I have image as ndarray with 20 bands with the following shape:
(20, 2227, 3676) .
I'm trying to save it using rasterio with the following script:

```
savedir=pathlib.Path('myfolder/')
savedir.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)


with rasterio.open(savedir /'myImage.tif', 
                                'w',
                                driver='GTiff',
                                height=img.shape[1],
                                width=img.shape[2],
                                count=20,
                                dtype=img.dtype,
                                crs=img_crs,
                                nodata=None, # change if data has nodata value
                                transform=img_transform) as dst:  
        
        for n in np.arange(0,20,1):
                dst.write(img[n,:,:],n+1)
```

This fails with he following error:

> ---> 17                 dst.write(img_arr[n,:,:],n+1)
>
> File rasterio/_io.pyx:1700, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.write()
>
> TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()

I'm not sure what is the source of this error, but I know that if I use the same script but instead of iterating through the bands I put manualy each band, it works.  for example:

```
dst.write(img_arr[0,:,:],1)
dst.write(img_arr[1,:,:],2)
...
dst.write(img_arr[19,:,:],20)
```

That works.

Hence, I don't know why I get the type error, and I don't waant to put manually all the bands of the image. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Juste one question, why don't you do `dst.write(img)` ?

Comment: well usually if I don't specifiy the shape and the specific band, it get mismatched / fail

Comment: You cannot have a mismatch between height/width/count if you specify them correctly :
 count=img.shape[0], height=img.shape[1], width=img.shape[2]

Comment: Ho, I just saw, but the driver should be "GTiff" -> https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#saving-raster-data

Comment: thank you for this! that happened when I edited it from the original code, I have used GTiff originally :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `dtype` of the `img` array that's the problem, it's your `n` variable.

`rasterio` is expecting a python `int` not a `numpy.int64` for the band number.

```
# this works
for n in range(0,1):
    dst.write(img[n,:, :], n+1)

# this works too
for n in np.arange(0,1):
    dst.write(img[n,:, :], int(n+1))

# this works for me
dst.write(img)

# this fails with `TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()`
for n in np.arange(0,1):
    dst.write(img[n,:, :], n+1) # n is np.int64 not int
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of GDAL are you using ? It seems that tyou need a `GDAL > 3.5.0` to have the support of writing INT64 dtype: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3325 (and `rasterio > 1.3.0`)

But do you really need INT64 ? It is really heavy on disk and usually useless.

Comment: I haven't downlaoded gdal to my venv. I'm using "rasterio==1.3.5.post1" , not sure where this post1 came from, to be honest.  and for the data type - no , I don't neeed int64, the bands are either uint8 or float

Comment: OK, rasterio 1.3.5 includes GDAL 3.5, no issue from that point of view. However, I strongly suggest you to convert your img to the dtype you really need, it will save you a lot of disk space